# ПОмогите как написать бота чтобы отправлял сообщение

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

как написать бота который будет по кнопке отправлять написанное человеком другому человеку.
вот что есть покамисть. Использую pyTelegramBotAPI

```
from telebot import types 

bot = TeleBot("")

TO_CHAT_ID = 2080813264 


def response(message):
  print(message.text) 
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id,message.text)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):

  keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
  keyboard.row("Гайд","Жалоба")
  keyboard.row("Анкета на набор")
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Типа приветствие',reply_markup=keyboard)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

def start(message):
  if message.text  == "Гайд":
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"тут типа гайд росписаный")



  if message.text == "Жалоба":
    save = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Введите вашу жалобу")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(save,response)
def message(msg):
    if msg.text == "Жалоба":  # Условые пересылки сообщения
        bot.forward_message(chat_id=2080813264,  from_chat_id=msg.chat.id, 
message_id=msg.message_id)



bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понял, чего вы хотите. Но могу предложить что-то такое.

```py
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot_token = "YOUR_BOT_TOKEN"
to_chat_id = 2080813264
bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    button = types.KeyboardButton("Send Message")
    markup.add(button)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет! Нажми на кнопку \"Send Message\", чтобы отправить сообщение", reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == "Send Message")
def send_message(message):
    user_message = message.text
    bot.send_message(to_chat_id, user_message)  # Отправка сообщения другому пользователю с id равным to_chat_id


bot.polling()
```